# php template idea

Tags: php, model-view-controller, scala, lift

So basically I have got an idea and I want to hear your opinions and what would be the best way to implement such method.

So basically I am using MVC at the moment but I feel this is a bit of an overkill for web development.

What I am thinking about is to port the lift templating system (liftweb.com) to php, so basically you have:

index.html:

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body><myFramework:controller.action /></body>
```

So basically the myFramework is just the name of the app, the controller and action would be pointing to:

```
class Controller{
    function action(){
        echo 'hello world';
    }
}
```

Also supporting things like: `<myFramework:lang key="helloWorld" />` -> Hello World (translated)

so this would return hello world. What would be the best way to develop such feature, and would this work with high performance, would this be an good idea?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Oh no, here it comes ... the 'templates are _3v1L_ and pointless' flame war. ARgggggg! Quick! Hide!

Comment: MVC and templating systems are two very different creatures... a template system is not a replacement for an MVC framework or vice versa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use templating systems! They are tottaly useless (do some research in google, or here).

The thing you need is HMCV. A beautiful framework like Kohana offers it, and it's not bloated, it's easy to understand, commented really well. I'm not regretting switching to it not a second.

Kohana offers translating like this: `<?=__("This phrase will be translated");?>`

Answer (score 0):

Use Smarty. It's easy, it's clean, not yet bloated, but soon it will be ;).

[Smarty](http://www.smarty.net)

Comment: No. Using a templating system on top of PHP which happens to be a template engine itself is redundant. See Briedis answer instead.

Comment: PHP's own "templating" is cumbersome. Ah if you are a robot, then go for it :).